# What is the difference between index.php/$1 and index.php?$1

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

What is the difference between `index.php/$1` and `index.php?$1`?

I have set `mod_rewrite` to `on` and my `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On      
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,PT,L] #<------if change to index.php?$1, it's working!!!
</IfModule>
```

When I now access `http://myhost.com/fadf/dsf/`, then I receive the following error:

> No input file specified.

But if I change `index.php/$1` to `index.php?$1`, it is working.

Comment: my php run as fastcgi , is "index.php/$1" not work in fastcgi ?

Answer (score 1):

## index.php/$1

This is "PATH_INFO" in HTTP parlance, Given a url like

```
http://example.com/path/script.php/extra/stuff
```

Then the server will invoke `/path/script.php`, and the `/extra/stuff` will be put into `$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]`

## index.php?$1

This is a standard http url with a query string. Given a url like

```
http://example.com/path/script.php?foo
```

Then within the script you will have `$_GET['foo']` be set. It won't have a value, but it will exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference is that index.php/$1 is `base64_encode()` and index.php?$1 is standard http url.

You may also check the [Base64 variants table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table).

Answer (score 0):

The first variant is for url parts divided by slashes, variant with index.php?$1 is for parameters, which are held in `$_REQUEST['somekey'] = "somevalue"`.